# ASP.NET MVC DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and I'm currently studying Entity Framework as a way to extract data from a database.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
    Employee[] employees = employeeContext.Employees;
    return View();
}
```

But I'm kindda confused in what variable should I put my `employeeContext.Employees` so that after that I can pass it to the view. I thought something like array.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Why can't you pass your `employees` variable to the view?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: return View(employees);  not sure why you might want an array unless your view specifically requires it?

Comment: I also don't understand what the problem is.  What's preventing you from passing it to the view?

Comment: firstly I can't assign employeeContext.Employees to employees
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<EntityFrameworkTest3.Models.Employee>' to 'EntityFrameworkTest3.Models.Employee[]' EntityFrameworkTest3 D:\Visual Studio\Projects\EntityFrameworkTest3\EntityFrameworkTest3\Controllers\HomeController.cs 15 Active

Comment: @peter - did you bother to read my answer below? That is point 1 on the list...

Comment: @Igor strange thing is that I am getting index out of range exception when I try `@Model[0].id`
`@Model[0].Name`

Comment: @peter - you have no employees in the table which results in an empty array so getting the first item will result in an index of out range exception

Comment: @Igor I have...

Comment: @Igor Oh sry now I see that I had mispelled my table name... anyway getting this exception now System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'EmployeeContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).'

Comment: Please read through [ask] a question. I helped you below with the code but if you have problems with every step you need to either do a little research yourself along the way or post a new question when you have a new problem.

Comment: @Igor anyway would you recommend some tutorials for MVC.. I'm quite new

Comment: @peter You need Entity Framework tutorials, not MVC.  There are plenty out there.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are getting a type mismatch on the `Employee[] employees = employeeContext.Employees` because `employeeContext.Employees` is a `DbSet<Employee>` and not an array.
2. You need to pass a model to your view, you can do this with the overload of method `View()`.
3. You need to dispose of the `DbContext` in a `using` block, (*it implements `IDisposable` and you should follow that pattern for almost everything that implements this interface to ensure resources are freed when no longer in use*)

Also you probably really do not want to pass ALL of your employees each time, what if there are thousands?

Updated code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using(EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext())
    {
        Employee[] employees = employeeContext.Employees.ToArray(); // now it will return an array
        return View(employees); // pass employees to your view
    }
}
```

Comment: for now I am just experimenting :) that's why I pass everything